# Retrieve database table names and print them out

Tags: php, arrays, database, wordpress

This should be fairly simple. I've crafted an SQL query that dumps all matching database table names to an array. I want to print them out, yet for some reason I cannot. Please help!

Database tables are named: example_1, example_2, etc.

My code:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'example_%'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Doing a print_r($results) shows that all the table names were successfully retrieved.
Example output:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Tables_in_wordpress (example_%)] => example_1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Tables_in_wordpress (example_%)] => example_2 ) )
```

So then I tried:

```
foreach($results as $res) {
  echo $res;
}
```

But no luck. How can I iterate through `$results` to print out each table name? Is there something like `$results[0].value` I could use to retrieve the values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is what you need to do:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach($results as $index => $value) {
    foreach($value as $tableName) {
        echo $tableName . '<br />';
    }
}
```

The => will separate the key and value from a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yup, that did it! You're the man. Thanks a bunch... just learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

```
global $wpdb;
$res = $wpdb->tables();
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: This is the right way to get the list of tables in WordPress.

Comment: This is giving only the WordPress default tables not the custom tables added by plugin or theme @Mybbor is the right way to get all table name from DB

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified using `array_column`.

```
$tables = array_column( $wpdb->get_results("show tables"), "Tables_in_local" );

foreach( $tables as $table ) {
    echo $table;
}
```