# How to retrieve all table names from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve all table names from a MySQL database and link them to a dropdown list. Then I want to store those table names in a table and preview them.

here's my code...

```
<?php 
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $ip";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="newloay.php">
<select name="select" id="select" required>
    <?php
     while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <option> <?php print $row[0] ?> </option>
    <?php 
     }  ?>

    }
</select>
```

Comment: table is huge but the table names are claims complains users items photo latelyfound

Comment: You could probably just populate the drop down list directly with a query instead of storing the table names in another table, unless you're using those names with some other data. Even then, you could still use a join to fetch each table name from MySQL's schema.

Comment: From PHP.net, on the `mysql_*` extension: `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.`

Comment: This answer here will help with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439165/retrieve-database-table-names-and-print-them-out.

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL** :

```
SELECT 
  table_name
FROM 
  my_schema.tables
```

Where `my_schema` is your schema name , `$ip`, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following code to get the Name of the Tables in your Database :

```
<?php
$dbname = 'mysql_dbname';

if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Hope this helps, for more details on this, please check out [THIS PAGE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php)

Comment: While the function `mysql_list_tables()` looks promising, it is not in the code you propose. If this is intentional, why the link?

Comment: And, in the function description: `This function is deprecated. It is preferable to use mysql_query() to issue an SQL SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name] [LIKE 'pattern'] statement instead.` It is deprecated even for a deprecated API.